# how can i add $ sign just before matching tag of span

Tags: html, replace, find, notepad++

```
<span class="xyz">z
      <span>abc</span>
      <span>cdf</span>
 </span>
```

This is my sample code
and must replace like this

```
<span class="xyz">z
      <span>abc</span>
      <span>cdf</span>
 $</span>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can't do such job with regex. Use a parser with your favorite scripting anguage. [You can't parse xml with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 0):

A very basic solution would be `/(<span[^>]*>)(.*?)(<\/span>)/`

https://regex101.com/r/BbTxJ3/1

I don't know what regex flavor notepad++ uses, so I can't say that the replace code would be the same, but I'm sure you'll be able to work with this

Comment: <span class="katex-html" aria-hidden="true">z</span>
It must work with specific class says katex, there are more middle span tags for which it should not be replaced. (Only entry level span tag with specific class)
note pad++ with HTML

Comment: Update your question to include all this information, I answered based on the currently available information in the question. I still don't know how to read minds