# how can i add $ sign just before matching tag of span </span> to $</span>, must work with specific class in python

Tags: python, html, replace, find

`<span class="abc">z <span class="xyz">123</span> <span>456</span> </span>`

Must work with specific class says 'abc' in the example

`<span class="abc">z <span class="xyz">123</span> <span>456</span> $</span>`

Comment: Pythons beautiful soup library is a good match for this use case. Regex is not.

Comment: How is this question different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75769019/how-can-i-add-sign-just-before-matching-tag-of-span which was closed recently. It was  closed because it needed more details and more clarity.

Comment: please kindly guide me, i dont have knowledge of python

Comment: Why do you now mention Python in a comment when it is not mentioned anywhere in this question or the previous question? Please read the [help] pages about how to write a good question that is suitable for this site.